# Makefile: When the function will be called

Tags: makefile

We ready to create the target file about ucore.img

```
$(kernel):
    @echo test

$(call create_target,kernel)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
bootblock = $(call totarget,bootblock)

$(bootblock): $(call toobj,boot/bootasm.S) $(call toobj,$(bootfiles)) 
    @echo + ld $@

$(call create_target,bootblock)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
$(call create_target_host,sign,sign)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# create ucore.img
UCOREIMG    := $(call totarget,ucore.img)

$(UCOREIMG): $(kernel) $(bootblock)
    $(V)dd if=/dev/zero of=$@ count=10000

$(call create_target,ucore.img)
```

But I can't see when these function about `call` will be called

```
$(call create_target,kernel)
$(call create_target,bootblock)
$(call create_target,ucore.img)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question you're asking.  Because those functions appear as normal makefile statements, not inside a recipe or on the right hand side of a normal (recursive) assignment statement, they will be expanded as the makefile is parsed.

So, when make is reading your makefile and it sees the line:

```
$(call create_target,kernel)
```

it will expand that `call` function reference at that time, before trying to parse the next line.  You don't show us what any of the actual macro definitions are for `create_target`, `totarget`, `toobj` are so we can't provide any information about what the result of that expansion might be.